# Having trouble proving epsilon deltas of limits with roots

Tags: calculus, limits

I am having a big issue proving this equation... Specifically at the part that involves the roots. I can't seem to get $\sqrt{2x-1}/\sqrt{x-3} - \sqrt{7}$ to look like $x-4$ in terms of epsilon. In other words I don't know how I can algebraically manipulate the root part of this proof to make it look like the $x-4$ part of it.

[image: As far as I could get in the proof]

Comment: Try: $x-3=x-4+1$ and $2x-1=2(x-4)+7$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the calculation, rewrite
$$\frac{\sqrt{2x-1}}{\sqrt{x-3}}-\sqrt{7}$$
as 
$$\frac{\sqrt{2x-1}-\sqrt{7}\sqrt{x-3}} {\sqrt{x-3}}.$$
Multiply top and bottom by
$$\sqrt{2x-1}+\sqrt{7}\sqrt{x-3}.$$
On top you end up with $-5(x-4)$. Nice!

Now you need to ensure the new bottom is not too small. So first specify that $\delta\lt 3/4$. That ensures that $\sqrt{x-3}\gt \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Ahhh okay. Complex conjugates. So I re-did the problem and like you said I ended up with -5(x-4) on the top but now the bottom is a mess... I got Sqrr(x-3)(sqrr(2x-1)) + (sqrr(x-3)*sqrr(7) * (x-3)). Our teacher told us we basically have to get the right side of the epsilon delta proof to look like the left side... I still have no idea how to isolate the x-4 in terms of epsilon.

Comment: The bottom **is** a mess. But note that if $\delta\lt 3/4$, then $\sqrt{x-3}\gt 1/2$, and the term $\sqrt{2x-1}+\sqrt{7}\sqrt{x-3}$ is greater than $2$ (by quite a bit) so the bottom is $\gt 1$. So in absolute value the whole thing is $\lt 5|x-4|$. That means that if in addition to $\delta\lt 3/4$ we ask that $\delta\lt \epsilon/5$, we get that the whole thing is $\lt \epsilon$.  Please tell me if this is not enough for you to push things through.

Comment: You cannot expect in general to "isolate." What we want to do is *estimate*.

Comment: Okay I think I'm starting to understand it. I don't however understand where 3/4 is coming from when you say delta < 3/4. Is it an arbitrary number? I appreciate that you're taking the effort to further explain things for me.

Comment: If $x$ is close to $3$, then the $\sqrt{x-3}$ which is a factor of the bottom could be small, which would spoil things. I picked $3/4$ out of (bad) habit, it makes $x-3\gt 1/4$, which makes $\sqrt{x+3}\gt 1/2$, a nice number. So at the end we pick $\delta=\min(3/4),t)$ where $t=\epsilon/5$. This is just insurance that we are technically correct if we are given a ridiculous $\epsilon$, like $10$. (Cont)

Comment: It maybe would have been better if I had said as a preliminary that we make sure $\delta\lt 1/10$. That forces $|x-3|\gt 0.9$, making the square root bigger than $\approx 0.94$. Then estimate the bottom as before. We get a much bigger estimate, which is "good", but unimportant for the *proof* of the limit result.

Answer (score 0):

Given any $\epsilon>0$, let $\delta = \min\{\epsilon/A, B\}$, where $A,B$ are some positive constants that we're going to figure out later. Then if $0<|x-4|<\delta$, observe that:
\begin{align*}
\left| \frac{\sqrt{2x-1}}{\sqrt{x-3}}-\sqrt{7} \right|
&= \left| \frac{\sqrt{2x-1}-\sqrt{7}\sqrt{x-3}} {\sqrt{x-3}} \right| \\
&= \left| \frac{\sqrt{2x-1}-\sqrt{7}\sqrt{x-3}} {\sqrt{x-3}} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{2x-1}+\sqrt{7}\sqrt{x-3}}{\sqrt{2x-1}+\sqrt{7}\sqrt{x-3}} \right| \\
&= \left| \frac{(2x-1)-7(x-3)} {\sqrt{x-3}(\sqrt{2x-1}+\sqrt{7}\sqrt{x-3})} \right| \\
&= \left| \frac{-5(x-4)} {\sqrt{x-3}(\sqrt{2x-1}+\sqrt{7}\sqrt{x-3})} \right| \\
&\leq \left| \frac{-5(x-4)} {\sqrt{x-3}(0+\sqrt{7}\sqrt{x-3})} \right| \qquad\text{since }\sqrt{2x-1}\geq0\\
&= \left| \frac{-5(x-4)} {\sqrt{7}(x-3)} \right|\\
&= \left| \frac{-5}{\sqrt 7}  \right| \cdot \frac{1}{|x-3|} \cdot |x-4|\\
&=  \frac{5}{\sqrt 7} \cdot \frac{1}{|x-3|} \cdot |x-4|\\
&< \frac{5}{\sqrt 7} \cdot \frac{1}{C} \cdot \frac \epsilon A \qquad \text{since } |x-4|<\delta \leq \epsilon/A\\
&= \epsilon \\
\end{align*}

The hard part is figuring out $A,B,C$. Somehow, we need to choose $B$ such that $|x-4|<\delta \leq B \implies |x-3|>C$ for some $C>0$ so that $\dfrac{1}{|x-3|} < \dfrac1C$ (this justifies the second to last step). Once we've done that, it suffices to let $A = \dfrac{5}{C\sqrt 7}$ (this justifies the last step).

With this in mind, suppose we choose $B=1/2$. Then we have:
\begin{align*}
|x-4| &< 1/2 \\
-1/2 < x-4 &< 1/2 \\
1/2 < x-3 &< 3/2 \\
\end{align*}
Hence, we have $|x-3| > 1/2$, so we obtain $C=1/2$. Thus, we may let $A = \dfrac{10}{\sqrt 7}$.